# How to group concat from MySQL and not repeat the same value if next value is same as current value

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table (location) like this

```
id | loc id
1  | Location A
2  | Location B
3  | Location B
4  | Location C
5  | Location A
6  | Location B
7  | Location B
```

i want my result from MySQL to be like this

```
Location A, Location B, Location C, Location A, Location B
```

but this is what i get instead

```
Location A, Location B, Location B, Location C, Location A, Location B, Location
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use window function `LAG()` to filter out rows that have the same `locid` as the previous row:

```
select group_concat(t.locid order by t.id) locations 
from (
  select *, lag(locid) over (order by id) prev
  from location
) t  
where t.locid <> t.prev or t.prev is null
```

For previous versions and if there are not gaps between the `id`s you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select group_concat(locid order by id) locations 
from location l
where not exists (select 1 from location where locid = l.locid and id = l.id - 1)
```

If there are gaps between the `id`s then use a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause to get the value of `locid` of the previous `id`:

```
select group_concat(locid order by id) locations 
from location l
where l.locid <> coalesce(
  (select locid from location where id < l.id order by id desc limit 1), 
  ''
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28102b3b80dac9986934da83eada5d52).
Results:

```
> | locations                                              |
> | :----------------------------------------------------- |
> | Location A,Location B,Location C,Location A,Location B |
```

Comment: Thanks ! works for me :) i have been looking for this for a while.